# How do we need to choose $c$ such that $e^{-(cx)^2}<\varepsilon$?

Tags: inequality, exponential-function

So, this should be really simple: Let $$\varphi(x):=e^{-(cx)^2}\;\;\;\text{for }x\in\mathbb R$$ for some $c>0$ and $$\varphi_x(y):=\varphi\left(|x-y|\right)\;\;\;\text{for }x,y\in \mathbb R.$$ How should I use $c$ if I want that $$\varphi_x(x\pm h)<\varepsilon\;\;\;\text{for all }x\in\mathbb R\tag1,$$ where $h>0$ and $\varepsilon$ are given?

We should easily see that $$\varphi_x(y)<\varepsilon\Leftrightarrow|x-y|^2>\frac{-\ln\varepsilon}{c^2}\tag2$$ and hence $$\varphi_x(x\pm h)<\varepsilon\Leftrightarrow h^2>-\frac{\ln\varepsilon}{c^2}\tag3.$$

Now, assume I want to place the kernel $\varphi$ at $0.5$ such that the set where it is $>\varepsilon$ is precisely $[0,1)$. This amounts to taking $x=0.5$ and $h=\frac12$. However, if I choose $c$ accordingly and take $\varepsilon=1e-10$ for example, then this is what I get (https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i2d=true&i=plot+exp%5C%2840%29-%5C%2840%29-ln%5C%2840%291e-10%5C%2841%29*4%5C%2841%29*Power%5B%5C%2840%290.5-y%5C%2841%29%2C2%5D%5C%2841%29+from+y%3D0+to+1)

[image]

This is not what I intended; the "relevant support" of the function should have length $1$. If I now replace $h$ by $h=1$, then I get

[image]

what is what I was looking for in the first place. However, this plot contradicts my derivation above. What am I missing here?

Comment: Your derivation is correct. It is unclear (at least to me) what you are plotting (which function, with which value of $c$ and $\varepsilon$), and mostly: why you think these plots contradict the derivation.

Comment: @AnneBauval I've edited the question. Hopefully it is clear now.

Comment: You already have a perfectly fine answer, but just to add: I think the only thing that you are/were missing is visual intuition on just how small $10^{-n}$ is compared to $1$. Note that if the second picture is indeed what you wanted, then in essence you're taking $\varepsilon$ too small: this picture would also emerge if you took $h = 1/2,$ but increased $\varepsilon$ to about $1/300$. It's worth carefully considering just how much precision you need, which of course is determined by your application.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to your (correct) derivation, since in your 1st plot $h=0.5$ and $\varepsilon=10^{-10},$ you rightly took $$c^2=\frac{-\ln\varepsilon}{h^2}=40\ln(10).$$
Your plot is not surprising: the "relevant support" (i.e. the interval where $\varphi>10^{-10}$), is really $(0,1),$ but your $\varepsilon$ is so tiny that you allow values of $\varphi$ indiscernible from $0$ on this support.

And for the second one ($h=1$), keeping $\varepsilon=10^{-10},$ you rightly took $$c^2=\frac{-\ln\varepsilon}{h^2}=10\ln(10).$$ But your plot does not show [the full "relevant support", wich is now (-0.5,1.5)](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i2d=true&i=plot+exp%5C%2840%29-10*ln%5C%2840%2910%5C%2841%29*Power%5B%5C%2840%290.5-y%5C%2841%29%2C2%5D%5C%2841%29+from+y%3D-0.5+to+1.5) and has the same problem as the first one.

Comment: I did not choose $c^2=10\ln(10)$, but $c^2 = -\ln(\varepsilon)2^2$.

Comment: The reason is that if the kernel should fill $[0,1]$, we need to take $h=\frac12$. Don't get what is wrong.

Comment: I know the reason why since it is that value I advised, and took in the 1st link in my answer, which gives the expected plot. But in your link you did choose $c^2=10\ln(10).$ This is why your (1st) plot was not what you wanted.

Comment: No, I did not. I chose $c^2=-\ln(\varepsilon)2^2$ with $\varepsilon=1e-10$. [Here](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i2d=true&i=plot+exp%5C%2840%29-%5C%2840%29-ln%5C%2840%291e-10%5C%2841%29*4%5C%2841%29*Power%5B%5C%2840%290.5-y%5C%2841%29%2C2%5D%5C%2841%29+from+y%3D0+to+1) is the plot.

Comment: Oh sorry indeed, I did not read the "*4" after your "-ln(1e-10)". But *4 or not *4 does not change the problem: you did not choose the $c$ corresponding (by your correct derivation) to the "$\varepsilon=\frac12$" you planned. That $c$ is indicated in my answer, with a link to the plot you expected.

Comment: You mean $h=\frac12$ - not $\varepsilon=\frac12$ - I guess. However, we need to choose $$c^2=-\frac{\ln(\varepsilon)}{h^2}.$$ If $h=\frac12$, then this yields $$c^2=-4\ln(\varepsilon).$$ And this is how I chose $c^2$ in [this plot](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i2d=true&i=plot+exp%5C%2840%29-%5C%2840%29-ln%5C%2840%291e-10%5C%2841%29*4%5C%2841%29*Power%5B%5C%2840%290.5-y%5C%2841%29%2C2%5D%5C%2841%29+from+y%3D0+to+1). Starting to feel stupid ...

Comment: I mean *both* equal to $\frac12,$ like *you* wrote. And I deed agree $c^2=-4\ln\varepsilon.$ This is why I wrote $c=2\sqrt{\ln2}$ in my answer. Your (repeated) first plot is not what you expected because you did not take $\varepsilon=\frac12.$ In my (first) plot, the "relevant support", i.e. the interval where $\varphi\ge\frac12$ is, as you wanted, "precisely [0,1)" hence "has length $1$". *I also* feel stupid. Could you please edit your post to clarify your question?

Comment: Sorry, that was a typo in the question; it should be $\varepsilon=1e-10$ and as you can see from the wolfram alpha link, this is the value I used to plot the picture. So, the confusion remains ...

Comment: Yes, I saw you were taking that value for ε
 in your plot, whence the question at the beginning of my answer about this self-contradiction. Since you changed your post, I had to change my answer.